# AppSocket/HP JetDirect - how to find host and port number

Tags: printing

In connecting to a network printer using AppSocket/HP JetDirect, how does one determine the host and port number?

Answer (score 1):

The host is the printer itself. You have to configure the JetDirect card in the printer to a proper IP address. Is the printer use autoconfigure options (like dhcp - what mostly is a bead idea) you may print the configurtion of the JetDirect card from the printer status menu.

The port normaly is TCP/9100 for the raw-printing protocol. Have a look [here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=57865&docId=emr_na-c02480766&docLocale=en_US) for a overview of used ports.